# What brand is a kitchen sink with this logo?

Tags: kitchen-sink

I'm trying to identify a kitchen sink. We try to replace it, but want to keep the granite counters, so we need to find the same brand with the same line so that the dimension matches

It has a logo on the inside (see image), the only other mark is a date stamped in ink on the bottom from 2005.

[image: Image of logo]

Answer (score 4):

A google search brought up a similar logo for Artisan sinks. A fleur de lys with the two extra stems.